# Count condition in CASE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

I am trying to get a conditional values based on count of error codes and their occurrences in specific time period from SQL query, but this query that I have written returns the first satisfied condition for all records.

What am I doing wrong

```
SELECT ERROR_CODE,
       CASE
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 2)
                      AND ERROR_CODE = '50001') > 50 THEN 'RED'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 2)
                      AND ERROR_CODE = '50001') < 50 THEN 'GREEN'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
                      AND ERROR_CODE IS NULL) > 100 THEN 'RED'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
                      AND ERROR_CODE IS NULL) < 100 THEN 'GREEN'
       END AS ALERT_COLOR
FROM   ERROR_LOG
GROUP  BY ERROR_CODE
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
50005   05-JAN-15 11.05.51.570000000 AM
50001   05-JAN-15 02.39.57.840000000 PM
50001   05-JAN-15 02.31.06.700000000 PM
50001   05-JAN-15 02.21.49.350000000 PM
50001   05-JAN-15 01.59.13.910000000 PM
50001   05-JAN-15 01.50.05.900000000 PM
50001   05-JAN-15 01.30.19.270000000 PM
50001   05-JAN-15 01.11.10.510000000 PM
50001   05-JAN-15 12.00.00.720000000 PM
        05-JAN-15 09.42.10.670000000 AM
        05-JAN-15 09.37.31.590000000 AM
```

DESIRED OUPUT (change the count condition to see the desired output)
**COUNT**

```
        2
 50001  8
 50005  1
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT ERROR_CODE,
       CASE
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 2)
                      AND ERROR_CODE = '50001') between 5 and 100 THEN 'RED'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 2)
                      AND ERROR_CODE = '50001') < 5 THEN 'GREEN'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
                      AND ERROR_CODE IS NULL) > 100 THEN 'RED'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
                      AND ERROR_CODE IS NULL) between 5 and 100 THEN 'GREEN'
       END AS ALERT_COLOR
FROM   ERROR_LOG
GROUP  BY ERROR_CODE
```

*Result*

```
Error_code   Alert_color
             GREEN
50005        ''
50001        RED
```

Comment: I can see where the 2/8/1 counts are coming from, but how is that translating to GREEN/null/RED? With those numbers you'd get null/RED/null, since your case has no handler for codes 50005 or null, and the 50001 count of 8 hits the first (red) condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're repeating the subqueries within each `when` clause for every row in the table, with no correlation. The subquery:

```
          (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
           FROM   ERROR_LOG
           WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 2)
                  AND ERROR_CODE = '50001')
```

... is going to evaluate to 8 every time, for every row in the table; so regardless of the error code that's actually in that row, the first branch of the case will always match, so you see `RED` for every row.

Repeating the subquery is inefficient, even if you correlated it. Oracle will optimise/cache it but still... it would be better to generate your counts once:

```
select error_code,
  count(case when cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 2) then 1 end) as cnt_2_day,
  count(case when cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 1) then 1 end) as cnt_1_day
from error_log
where cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 2)
group by error_code
order by error_code nulls first;

ERROR_CODE CNT_2_DAY  CNT_1_DAY
---------- --------- ----------
(null)             2          2 
50001              8          8 
50005              1          1
```

All of your sample data is less than one day old, so the counts are the same; if you had data from two days ago they'd differ.

You can then use that - once - as an inner query (or CTE if you prefer) and use the results as input to another level of `case` to convert into your colour codes:

```
select error_code,
  case
    when error_code = '50001' and cnt_1_day between 5 and 100 then 'RED'
    when error_code = '50001' and cnt_2_day < 5 then 'GREEN'
    when error_code is null and cnt_1_day > 100 then 'RED'
    when error_code is null and cnt_1_day between 5 and 100 then 'GREEN'
    else null
  end as alert_colour
from 
(
  select error_code,
    count(case when cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 2) then 1 end) as cnt_2_day,
    count(case when cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 1) then 1 end) as cnt_1_day
  from error_log
  where cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 2)
  group by error_code
)
order by error_code nulls first;

ERROR_CODE ALERT_COLOUR
---------- ------------
(null)     (null)       
50001      RED          
50005      (null)
```

Which doesn't match the result you said you expected, but as I said in a comment, I'm not sure how you got from the numbers to the result you showed. Your buckets exclude a lot of possibilities; you might want the first condition to just be `> 5` for example. You're completely ignoring `50005`, which you expected to see. If your underlying logic is that any code set uses the 2-day count and nulls use the 1-day count - which is a leap - then you could generalise it a bit to:

```
select error_code,
  case
    when error_code is not null and cnt_not_null between 5 and 100 then 'RED'
    when error_code is not null and cnt_not_null < 5 then 'GREEN'
    when error_code is null and cnt_null > 100 then 'RED'
    when error_code is null and cnt_null between 5 and 100 then 'GREEN'
    else null
  end as alert_colour
from (
  select error_code,
    count(case when cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 2)
      and error_code is not null then 1 end) as cnt_not_null,
    count(case when cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 1)
      and error_code is null then 1 end) as cnt_null
  from error_log
  where cret_dtim > trunc(sysdate - 2)
  group by error_code
)
order by error_code nulls first;

ERROR_CODE ALERT_COLOUR
---------- ------------
(null)     (null)       
50001      RED          
50005      GREEN
```

Which still isn't your expected result, but will have to do until the logic (and my mistake) is explained, or your results are changed...

Comment: thorough and nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`case` Returns the `result_expression` of the first `input_expression = when_expression` that evaluates to `TRUE`. Try this.

```
SELECT ERROR_CODE,
       CASE
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 2)
                      AND ERROR_CODE = '50001') between 50 and 100 THEN 'RED'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 2)
                      AND ERROR_CODE = '50001') < 50 THEN 'GREEN'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
                      AND ERROR_CODE IS NULL) > 100 THEN 'RED'
         WHEN (SELECT Count(ERROR_CODE)
               FROM   ERROR_LOG
               WHERE  CRET_DTIM > Trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
                      AND ERROR_CODE IS NULL) between 50 and 100 THEN 'GREEN'
       END AS ALERT_COLOR
FROM   ERROR_LOG
GROUP  BY ERROR_CODE
```

Comment: @NullPointerException - can you show some sample records and desired result.

Comment: I added the sample data